# Is there a shorter way to check a condition before each line of code without repeating the condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

I'm trying to make a failsafe with pyautogui. Having to move my mouse cursor to the corner is very difficult at times. Below is a sample of what my code is suppose to do when this key bind is active. It works, but I want to see if there is a better way of writing this code without having to repeat each condition every time. I want to be able to perform the failsafe at anytime during the loop instead of having to wait until the beginning of each iteration.

this is what I want my code to do:

```
import pyautogui
import sys
from win32.lib.win32con import VK_CAPITAL
from win32.win32api import GetKeyState

def check():
    if GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) == 1:
        sys.exit()

for i in range(10):
    check()
    pyautogui.move(100,200, duration=1)
    check()
    pyautogui.move(200,200, duration=1)
    check()
    pyautogui.move(200,300, duration=1)
    check()
```

this is what it looks like right now:

```
import pyautogui
import sys
from win32.lib.win32con import VK_CAPITAL
from win32.win32api import GetKeyState

def check():
    if GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) == 1:
        sys.exit()

for i in range(10):
    check()
    pyautogui.move(100,200, duration=1)
    pyautogui.move(200,200, duration=1)
    pyautogui.move(200,300, duration=1)
```

Comment: reopen. I edited the example. It should give more clarity as to what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Given the update, put the inner loop code into another loop that runs over `range(3)`. Seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) though. There's probably a better way to do this but I'm not familiar enough with pyautogui or the need for a fail safe to say for sure. Question is much clearer than before though, thanks for the update.

Comment: The reason for my own failsafe and not pyautogui's is that it requires me to move the mouse cursor to the corner of the screen and at times it becomes very difficult. If anything pops up on the screen the program will continue running regardless of what errors occur, and It would be easier to press a keybind rather than trying to move the cursor to the corner especially at the speed that its going at. Also the xy are positions on the screen. I edited the post as well.

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense. No, the XY problem is totally unrelated to coordinates on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a list of callable actions and iterate the list while checking for your condition.  The following will call the function list until the caps lock key is active:

```
import sys
import time
from win32.lib.win32con import VK_CAPITAL
from win32.win32api import GetKeyState

def check():
    if GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) == 1:
        print('exiting...')
        sys.exit()

def move(x,y,duration):
    print(f'move to {x},{y}')
    time.sleep(duration)

funcs = (lambda: move(100,200,duration=1),
         lambda: move(200,200,duration=1),
         lambda: move(200,300,duration=1))

while True:
    for func in funcs:
        check()
        func()
```

Comment: I like the way you wrote the title **Vague answer to a vague question**. I was about to write a comment to the author to be specific.

Comment: I do too, but truth told if you have to write that sort of thing it's probably a "vote to close" thing. This may help OP though but probably little value for future visitors. :\

Comment: Yeah I should of been more specific about the question. I edited it to add more clarity.

Comment: @E-O I edited the question based on your question edit.   Voted to re-open as well.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Thanks for the feedback. This method works great. For some reason my win32api isn't importing GetKeyState, but I just replaced it with the keyboard module.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach,

```
def func1():
   print('func1')
def func2():
   print('func1')
def func3():
   print('func1')

funcs_map['cond1'] = func1
funcs_map['cond2'] = func2
funcs_map['cond3'] = func3

def get_condition(i:int) -> str:
    if(i == 1):
       return 'cond1'
    elif(i == 2):
       return 'cond2'
    else:
       raise ValueError(f'Unknown i value: {i} to get a condition')


for i in range(x):
   func_ptr = funcs_map[get_condition(i)]
   func_ptr()
```